# How to: Create an asp.net Project from Existing Code Files

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a source for an asp.net project (with vb.net behind). Is there a way to easily create a project for it? I know that I can just copy and paste the source into a blank project, but I noticed that e.g. VS 2013 has functionality "Project From Existing Code". But it seems like it cannot create an asp.net project. I wonder if there is something new that I don't know which would let me accomplish this task.

Thanks.

Comment: i personally think, that even if there was a tool to do that, creating an empty project and copying the files inside would still be way faster

Comment: Isn't there next-to-nothing inside a web project type anyway?!  It's just a solution/project file with a list of the aspx/etc. files!  When the code is published to a web site it usually (IME) have the project files and other gumphf with it anyway; configuration is in web.config!

Comment: OK, I will try that. Thanks Banana and Grim.\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way to do it but like the comments stated if you want to do it fast then just create the empty project and pull the files in.

Here's how you create the project by using the files.

1. You can go to IIS and create a website
2. Give the site a name
3. Use the file directory that your files are in for the physical path.
4. Choose a port to display the site on
5. Open up Visual Studios and select File > Open > Web Site
6. Make sure Local IIS is selected (if not click on Local IIS box)
7. Select the website name you just created